# How to design architecture for scalable algo trading application?

Tags: python, server, architecture, celery, algorithmic-trading

I was using Django-python framework for my web app. When I build a strategy in the UI it gets converted into a .py script file and every 5 mins (can be variable based on my candle interval) the file gets executed. I was using celery beat to invoke the file execution and the execution happens on the same machine using celery.

Here the problem is actually with scalability, if I have more strategies my CPU and memory usage were going more than 90%. How do I design the server architecture so that it can scale. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When one Celery worker is no longer enough, you create more. This is quite easy if you are on a cloud platform where you can easily create more virtual machines.

If you can't create more, than you have to live with the current situation and try to spread the execution of your strategies across a longer period of time (throughout the day I suppose).